# Javascript get substring values within the curly braces

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I was looking for regexp to get values in between the curly braces, but the examples found on internet are limited to just one substring while I need to get **all the substrings** values which are matching the pattern.
eg:

```
The {Name_Student} is living in {City_name}
```

How can I get the values of substrings in between the curly braces({}), in an array if possible! I am trying to implement this in javascript.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `str.match(/\{([^}]+)\}/g)`

Comment: I really don't understand Why I got a negative point here?

Comment: Because you didn't show any effort, you got answers because this question is very easy, and ppl like them points.

Comment: @elclanrs i never post in a place like this before researching a bit about it. i tried a lot of examples and as I said in the post I was not getting array list instead i just got one substring match.

Comment: We expect to see code, that's the main problem, otherwise it's a good question, if you post the code here and a demo that shows what you tried so far, then ppl will upvote.

Comment: @elclanrs anyway i am not removing this post fearing further point loss. maybe it will be helpful for someone else like me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match the values, then remove the curlys:

```
str.match(/\{.+?\}/g).map(function(x){return x.slice(1,-1)})
```

Or you can do this with capture groups:

```
var res = []
str.replace(/\{(.+?)\}/g, function(_, m){res.push(m)})
```

Answer (score 2):

The regex `{([^}]+)}` captures all the matches to Group 1 (see the captures in the right pane of [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/22)). The code below retrieves them.

**In JavaScript**

```
var the_captures = []; 
var yourString = 'your_test_string'
var myregex = /{([^}]+)}/g;
var thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
while (thematch != null) {
    // add it to array of captures
    the_captures.push(thematch[1]);
    document.write(thematch[1],"<br />");    
    // match the next one
    thematch = myregex.exec(yourString);
}
```

**Explanation**

- We capture the strings to Group 1. The code retrieves them and adds them to an array.
- `{` matches the opening brace
- `([^}]+)` captures all chars that are not a closing brace to Group 1
- `}` matches the closing brace

Answer (score 1):

The below regex would capture the values inside curly braces into the first group.

```
\{([^}]*)\}
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/wN4wB7/4)

Comment: hi thanks for the answer, but is there anyway to strip off { and } from the front and the back of the substring?

Comment: just print the group1.

Comment: @Ganesh: If you use the above with `string.match`, the resulting array will have two entries. The second entry has just the contents of the capture group (the bit between the `{}`): `var m = "testing {one} testing".match(/\{([^}]*)\}/); if (m) { console.log(m[1]); }` shows `"one"`.